# Create function not defined in ZMQ header file - MQL4

Tags: zeromq, mql4, metatrader4, mt4

I got issue about header file in MetaTrader 4. I'm using ZMQ libraries and header files. It worked good,but without changing anything something went wrong, exactly: "create function not defined". This error occured in Mql/Lang/GlobalVariables.mqh file which is for ZMQ.